# Can you get the DOM state before it has mutated (MutationObserver API)

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I am using the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen to DOM mutations:

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('mutation:', mutation);
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

When receiving a childList mutation, I would like to know the state of the DOM before the mutation.
But when the callback is called, it is already after.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Save necessary DOM parts on each callback invocation into some `prevDom` variable?

Comment: And if I am listening to the entire document? no way to get the prevState?

Comment: `MutationRecord` has a property called `oldValue` but it's always null for `childList` mutations.